# Macro to loop through all sheets in the workbook, test if a cell has a certain value. If yes, copy certain data to be pasted

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a project that requires the following:

Looping through all worksheets in a workbook, if cell A1 value equal XXYY then select row 7 ctrl down until end of content then copy

Consolidate all the copied data into one worksheet starting from row 10 in the consolidated worksheet

Comment: Good luck. You can do it.... if you ever have any questions, come back here and ask, ok? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try...

```
Sub Macro1()
Worksheets.Add Before:=Sheets(1)
ActiveSheet.Name = "Consolidate"
For i = 2 To Worksheets.Count
Sheets(i).Select

If Sheets(i).Range("A1").Value Like "*XXYY*" Then
    Sheets(i).Rows("7:7").Select
    Sheets(i).Tab.Color = 5287936
    Sheets(i).Range(Selection, Sheets(i).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Select
    Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Consolidate").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
End If
Next i
Sheets("Consolidate").Select
Sheets("Consolidate").Rows("2:9").Insert
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked i would also like it to color those tabs that have XXYY in green

Comment: Its coloring all tabs not the ones with XXYY

Comment: I figured it out i just had to move its position below the if statement. Thanks very much!!!